# Calculating power of a quantum computer for RSA

Tags: quantum-algorithms, experimental-realization, cryptography, shors-algorithm

As discussed [in this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/), the expected security of 1024-bit RSA is 80-bits:

> [NIST SP 800-57](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57_part1_rev3_general.pdf) §5.6.1 p.62–64 specifies a correspondence between RSA modulus size $n$ and expected security strength $s$ in bits:
>
> ```
> Strength  RSA modulus size
>   80        1024
>  112        2048
>  128        3072
>  192        7680
>  256       15360
> ```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Q_System_One), we now have a 20-qubit quantum computer:

> IBM Q System One is a 20-[qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) computer.

**Question:** If we tried to use a 20-qubit computer, e.g. IBM Q System One, to calculate the $\sim {2}^{80}$ keys in the 1024-bit RSA keyspace, how long would it take?

Comment: Related:  ["_What does a “real” quantum computer need for cryptanalysis and/or cryptographic attack purposes?_"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40904/what-does-a-real-quantum-computer-need-for-cryptanalysis-and-or-cryptographic) from SE.Cryptography.

Comment: Related: ["_Applicability of IBM's projected 50-qubit quantum computer Q to cryptanalysis?_"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44472/) from SE.Cryptography.

Comment: Can you clarify what the quantum computer is supposed to do? That is, what does it mean to "calculate a key"?

Comment: That means brute force, calculate all possible combinations of 1024 bit encryption key, it is related to one of my questions in the crypto.StackExchange [https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70829/how-long-does-it-take-to-crack-rsa-1024-with-a-pc]

Comment: Related: [*"How to factor 2048 bit RSA integers in 8 hours using 20 million noisy qubits"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09749) by Gidney & Ekerå.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "If we tried to use a 20-qubit computer to
> calculate the ∼280 keys in the 1024-bit RSA keyspace, how long would
> it take?"

That depends on the speed of the gates, but you are unlikely to do anything useful associated with RSA cryptography with only 20 qubits, and you are even less likely to do anything useful with IBM's gate and measurement fidelities.